# Python datetime conversions from one local timezone to another (+ bonus DST's)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst, pytz

I'm having some trouble understanding why I'm getting the results I'm getting.

What I wanted to try:

1. Take two timezones, one that uses DST and one that doesn't. ex: Romania (dst) and Venezuela(no dst).
2. For the timezone that has dst, create two datetimes. One in the interval of the dst, and one that isn't. Romania DST interval (4-10 / April-October). Ex:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime
   from pytz import timezone

   tz1 = timezone('Europe/Bucharest')
   tz2 = timezone('America/Caracas')

   date1 = datetime(2016, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz1)  # its in the dst interval (5 o'clock, summer - dst)
   date1 = datetime(2016, 12, 5, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz1)  # isn't in the dst interval (5 o'clock, winter - no dst)

   x = date1.astimezone(tz2)
   y = date2.astimezone(tz2)
   ```
3. Shouldn't `x` and `y` have different hours? Because date1 is in the DST interval, so 5 o'clock should mean a different hour than 5 o'clock in date2 when the datetime isn't in the DST interval.

Yet, both `x` and `y` have the same hour when converted to a no DST timezone.

Thanks for any explanations you can spare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `datetime` constructor to use a `pytz` timezone, you must use `localize`:

```
date1 = tz1.localize(datetime(2016, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0))
date2 = tz1.localize(datetime(2016, 12, 5, 5, 0, 0))
```

From the [documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘‘does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.